# DataGridColumnHeader Style Continued

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

This question is a sequel of this question: [DataGridColumnHeader Style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24453443/3357699)

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Border BorderBrush="#DBDBDB"
                        BorderThickness="1 0 0 0"
                        Background="#00ECECEC"
                        Padding="3">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    <Border.Triggers>
                        ...
                    </Border.Triggers>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The above code shows my `Style` for the `DataGridColumnHeader` and `DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter`. The Triggers work how I want them but there are some small things I don't like. There is what I have right now below here.

***Image removed.***

The problem here is that the first cell has a border on its left. The reason for this is clear because I have this in my code: `BorderThickness="1 0 0 0"`.

***Image removed.***

The second problem is on the right of the header. If I `Hover` over a cell, the Trigger colors the cell grey. You can see that the grey overlays the `DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter` border because these cells are rectangular and the `DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter` has rounded corners.

***Image removed.***

I nearly have what I want and that is:

- One big border around the entire header with rounded corners.
- A 1 px line between every header cell.
- Hover effect that stays inside the outer border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to assign styles in my code behind instead of the xaml itself. Below is the code:

```
if (gridColumns.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gridColumns.Count; i++)
      {
            DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = gridColumns[i].ColumnName;
            column.Binding = new Binding(gridColumns[i].ColumnBinding);
            if (i == 0)
                column.HeaderStyle = (Style)this.FindResource("ColumnHeaderStyleLeft");
            else if (i == gridColumns.Count - 1)
                column.HeaderStyle = (Style)this.FindResource("ColumnHeaderStyleRight");
            else
                column.HeaderStyle = (Style)this.FindResource("ColumnHeaderStyleCenter");
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
        }
    }
```